# Do I need 10/2 or 10/3 wire for a 220V heater?

Tags: electrical, wire

I am wiring a receptacle for a 4800 watt (220) construction heater ( the standard type found in home stores). Do I need a neutral wire or not?  Do I use 10 awg wire 10/3 or 10/2.

Comment: What's the model number of the heater?  I'd have to guess that it's a 240 volt heater, but without knowing the exact model there's no way to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your load is 20 amps so you should use 10 awg.  Heaters are continuous loads, to size the wire correctly it is 125% of 20 amps or 25 amps. The fans usually run on 120v and they would require a neutral 10-3 with ground would be the proper wire.